# Android Image Cache/Web/Memory Library

Tags: android, networking, android-image

So I've created my own Android code to do a number of Image operations for Android. The functionality that is currently implemented is

1. Load Image from URL
2. Save image to SD Card
3. Prep SD Card image library with zip, downloaded when user installs application first time

While this is working okay, I'd like to switching to something more professional and full featured. I'm not really handling ListViews very gracefully and I'm sure my networking implementation is not nearly as robust as it should be. Furthermore, I'm not using any in-memory caching or recycling view properly.

I feel like a number of people that are smarter than I am have already solved this sort of image issue. Are there any well regarded libraries out there that will cover my use cases and help with these sorts of issues?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I decided to go with Square's Picasso library:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Does just about everything and is under aggressive development. The Square guys really know what they're doing!

Comment: Small and works neatly. Satisfied all my needs, including callback and placeholder. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this caching option from official Android Developers site

[Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)